# $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is not a UFD

Tags: field-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I am writing a short presentation (approximately 10 minutes long) on the topic of Fermat's Last Theorem. Obviously, the details presented will have to be pretty sparse but I am compiling a handout as well. Part of this handout will include theorems and results that I will use in my presentation but do not have time to prove.

One of the results I will be using is that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is not a unique factorisation domain, where $\zeta$ is is the $p$-th root of unity $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$.

I have searched the internet and found no explicit proof. The book I am reading, Number Fields by Daniel A. Marcus, says that the unique factorisation of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ fails for $p=23$. So clearly the proof can use this as a counter-example. Does anyone have a formal proof for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$ is a Dedekind ring, UFD is equivalent to PID. For $p=23$ we can give an ideal which is not principal, e.g., $\mathfrak p := (2,(1+\sqrt{-23})/2)$. Hence $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$ is not a UFD. This is due to Kummer.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a simple way to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p}]$ is a Dedekind ring? Or would I simply be showing that it is Noetherian etc?

Comment: It is easy. All rings of integers are Dedekind rings. And $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$ is the ring of integers of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]$

Comment: Of course, thank you very much.

Comment: On the other hand, all $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$ are UFD's for primes less than $23$.

Comment: So my book tells me. I find that quite interesting. Although the book skips on the details.

Comment: This leaves open the question of how to show $(2,(1+\sqrt{-23})/2)$ is not principal.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This has been shown here already, I think. Right now I only found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309664/prove-that-there-exists-a-non-principal-ideal-in-q-zeta-23) with a reference to Washington's book.