# $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a UFD, $\Rightarrow x+y\omega=u\alpha^{p}$

Tags: ring-theory

I am aware this is the same question as [If $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a UFD, then $x+y\omega=u\alpha^{p}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212305/if-mathbbz-omega-is-a-ufd-then-xy-omega-u-alphap). But it doesn't have an answer yet (or even any comments) and I am also interested in finding the solution.